# Problem with the semantic_map editor knowrob_gui running

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the semantic map editor is moved into knowrob_gui. But the tutorial and document has not been updated. Do anyone know what is the problem with this:

When I compiled the knowrob_gui successfully in groovy on Ubuntu 12.04 and run it

$rosrun knowrob_gui KnowRobGUI

It displays that:

*find: ‘/jre/lib/’: No such file or directory
Cannot find libjsig ... maybe you need to set JAVA_HOME?*

It is not clear in the tutorial in knowrob org

PS: @Moritz would you please update the tutorial if possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67200/problem-with--the-semantic_map-editor-knowrob_gui-running/) by [Rikardo](https://answers.ros.org/users/5410/rikardo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2013-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, the error message is rather clear, you need to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable. Google helps how to do this:

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java

You can either enter this command in the shell or add it to your ~/.bashrc to have it set automatically in every newly opened shell.

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2013-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rikardo](https://answers.ros.org/users/5410/rikardo/) on 2013-07-17**:
Thanks, I set the JAVA_HOME at first but not work. I re-installed a new system and it is OK, but new error occurred. It says [FATAL ERROR   Could not find system resources

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2013-07-17**:
Try setting the SWI_HOME_DIR environment variable as indicated here:
http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/FindResources.html

export SWI_HOME_DIR=/usr/lib/swi-prolog